# html-pdf npm library gives different output on windows & ubuntu

Tags: node.js, webkit, phantomjs, pdfrenderer, pdf-rendering

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf library which is based on **Phantom JS** which internally uses **webkit**. I'm pasting the dummy HTML & JS code(keep these files in 1 folder) and also attaching the output screenshot.

The issue I'm facing is that **on windows the PDF is generated with some extra space at top(empty space above red) which I can't get rid of**.

Here is a forum(outdated) discussing similar issues, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/YQIyxLWhmr0 .

**input.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="pageHeader" style="border-style: solid;border-width: 2px;color:red;">
        header   <br/> header       <br/> header   <br/> header
    </div>
<div id="pageContent" style="border-style: solid;border-width: 2px;color:green;">
    <div>
        body    <br/> body    <br/> body
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**
(You require path, fs, handlebars, html-pdf npm packages)

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var handlebars = require('handlebars');
var pdf = require('html-pdf');

saveHtml();

function saveHtml() {

fs.readFile('input.html', 'utf-8', {
    flag: 'w'
}, function(error, source) {
    handlebars.registerHelper('custom_title', function(title) {
        return title;
    })

    var template = handlebars.compile(source);
    var data = {};
    var html = template(data);

    var options = {
        'format': 'A4',
        'base': "file://",
        /* You can give more options like height, width, border */
    };
    pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./output.pdf', function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('err pdf');
            return;
        } else {
            console.log('no err pdf');
            return;
        }
    });
});

}
```

**Output on ubuntu**
[image: Output on ubuntu]

**Output on windows**
[image]

Extra space at top(empty space above red) in Windows is the issue.

**THINGS that didn't work**
1. Adding
    "border": {
        "top": "0px"            // or mm, cm, in
    }
 to options in JS file

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf#options

2. Giving fixed "height": "10.5in" & "width": "8in" in options in JS file
3. Making margin-top & padding-top to 0px/-50px to pageHeader div.
4. Overriding margin-top & padding of body to 0px/-20px in @media print in bootstrap.css
5. Giving fixed height to header

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can manually set the CSS property to html tag. In my case I was having problems developing the template in Windows and deploying it to Linux (Heroku).

I put `zoom: 0.7` in the label html and now both views look the same.

```
html{zoom: 0.7;}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, sorted my issue where Windows was displaying correctly but upload to Ubuntu server wasn't.

Comment: @Cristian : In my case pdf generater is generating extra page while it is blank, how did i resolve it?

Comment: You made my day!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get more consistent results by removing the ID's so that it treated everything as content rather than separate header and content areas.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="border-style: solid;border-width: 2px;color:red;">
            header
        </div>
        <div style="border-style: solid;border-width: 2px;color:green;">
            <div>
                body
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you need an ID for styling, use something other than pageHeader / pageFooter to avoid the special treatment associated with those IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a normalize style sheet to compensate for cross platform differences?

https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/